# Android simulator is not loading on react-native application (Expo)

Tags: react-native, android-studio, npm, expo, android-virtual-device

After the npm start, when the android simulator is open and running with Pixel3, if I 'click' a (for Android emulator), this error appears and the app does not open on the emulator

```
Trying to open the project on Android...
Installing Expo on device
-Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Failed to install C:\Users\Atif\.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.16.1.apk:

 Expo  Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
|
This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.io/tools
```

I also tried uninstalling and install again. Also I Tried Opening the emulator then run npm start.

Hope Someone Help me. But for whoever helped me i will appreciate their help. Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

first, turn off AVD , then restart start the system, and open AVD and expo project. it will work mostly. If not delete the previous Pixel3 device , restart the system and take a new device and try.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of access issue to open the emulator. Can you manually start a emulator device open, and check react-native run- android. Hopefully if the app is happy, it will install on the emulator.